# Fedora Repository for older Linux Kernel versions

Tags: vmware, fedora, kernel, repository

I'm using VMware Workstation 8 on Fedora. After every Kernel update, VMware can't rebuild its modules, so a patch is necessary. However, the last patch causes VMware to panic when a virtual machine is started (at least on my machine).

So I'd like to install an older Kernel, so VMware will build successfully without a patch. Unfortunately all older Kernels have been uninstalled when I upgraded from Fedora 16 to 17 and something like "yum install kernel-3.0" doesn't work (doesn't seem to exist in the repo).

Is there a repository with older Kernel versions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find and download older kernels from the Fedora Build System: http://koji.fedoraproject.org/koji/packageinfo?packageID=8.

Answer (score 3):

Latest VMWare Workstation 8.0.5 is shipped with kernel modules source code that compiles on both Fedora 16 and 17 3.x kernels and works without crashing. Previous versions needed a patch from other sources.
But i fear you will hit same problem that i do : after some time of use Guests are stopped some long seconds on disk access, this is very noticeable on My Windows Vista guest where mouse pointer just freeze longs seconds making system barely unusable.

Comment: +1 for the freeze warning - will try to avoid that.